# Android Push icon, sound and vibrate using Ionic.io Beta Push

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm currently migrating from ionic.io alpha to beta on my app and I noticed some strange behaviors:

1. The notification icon I setup on plugin config no longer shows
   up when I receive a notification. (If I send using the alpha API it
   works just fine)
2. The phone no longer plays the notification
   sound or vibrates (on alpha its working fine too)
3. I use a $state.go with a payload param on notification receiving. Using the
   alpha API, when the user clicks the notification or receive it with
   the app on foreground, he gets redirected just fine. Using te beta
   API he only gets redirected if the app is on the foreground.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
        "debug": true,
        "onNotification": function(notification) {
          var payload = notification.payload;
          console.log(notification, payload);
          $state.go(payload['$state'],payload['$stateParams']);
        },
        "onRegister": function(data) {
          push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
        },
        "pluginConfig": {
          "android": {
            "icon": "push_icon",
            "iconColor": "#F47D30"
          },
```

So, did anyone had a similar problem or could help me out figuring it out?

Comment: I also noticed notifications with the new API are not being handled by the PushPlugin using adb logcat.